# WebLogic's @AsyncWebService annotation location

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, weblogic11g

I'm implementing asynchronous web services for WebLogic 11g, following [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm) guide.

At some point it instructs to annotate the web service implementation class with @AsyncWebService. This annotation, or the package for that matter (oracle.webservices.annotations.async) is nowhere to be found. The guide instructs to install 'Oracle JRF Web Services Asynchronous services', which I cannot, but I don't think this contains the necessary dependencies, since it says it enables you to make use of the default JMS queues.

Where can I find the required jars containing the annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is part of the Oracle Fusion Middleware package for 11g (11.1.1).

I was using the zip package of WebLogic, which has no Middleware Home. Adding one in this distro is hard, so it's best to use the WebLogic Package Installer.